# PostgreSQL - With statement to have one table from many different

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 4 tables like that

```
table a:

art_id |  name | surname
-------+-------+--------
  1    | John  | McA
  2    | Alex  | McB
  3    | Juddy | McC

table b:
art_id is a foreign key to table a
diff_id is foreign key to table c

art_id | title | diff_id
-------+-------+--------
  1    | smth  | 1.1
  2    | else  | 1.2
  3    | here  | 1.3 

table c:
class is foreign key to table d

class  | date  | diff_id
-------+-------+--------
  a    | 01.02 | 1.1
  b    | 02.03 | 1.2
  c    | 03.04 | 1.3 

 table d:

class  | deputy|
-------+-------+
  a    | John  | 
  b    | Marc  | 
  c    | Sophie|
```

I'm trying to write a postresql statement to have a table like:

```
table result:

| title | deputy |
+-------+--------+
| smth  |  John  | 
| else  |  Marc  |
| here  | Sophie |
```

I am trying to do it by WITH AS statement bun at the moment I'm stuck.
After a creating recursive table in the statements I was trying to solve that problem by doing LEFT JOIN statement, but it multiplying the records in the result table.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Why do you need WITH or recursion? Wouldn't a simple join between b, c and d work?

Comment: I didn't try it. I need to collect diff_id for specific art_id, store that diff_id's to get class from table c, store that class to finally get deputy from table d. If you know how to do it faster and easier feel free to give me an advise :)!

Comment: `Select b.art_id, d.deputy from b join c on b.diff_id=c.diff_id join d on c.class=d.class` comes to mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating your task with recursive queries and storing immediate values. I believe simple `JOIN`s are sufficient for what you're trying to achieve.

```
SELECT
    b.title, d.deputy
FROM
    b
    INNER JOIN c ON b.diff_id = c.diff_id
    INNER JOIN d ON c.class = d.class
```

If you need titles to be shown when there are no matching values in deputy column, than you may need to change `INNER` to `LEFT` type of join.

Also, if you're receiving multiple results for one `title` with exactly the same values in `deputy` column consider adding a `DISTINCT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.title, d.deputy
FROM
    b
    INNER JOIN c ON b.diff_id = c.diff_id
    INNER JOIN d ON c.class = d.class
```

If you really feel like there's a need to include table `a` then rewrite the query:

```
SELECT
    b.title, d.deputy
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN b ON a.art_id = b.art_id
    INNER JOIN c ON b.diff_id = c.diff_id
    INNER JOIN d ON c.class = d.class
```

Comment: Thanks. Used 3rd part of your solution with my WITH AS statement and it works. 
Its more complicated than I described so I had to use recursive query to select diff_id from many rows by using art_id to separately catch them.
Thank you for help!